# Why do we need execution permission to change a directory in Unix?

Tags: unix, file-permissions

Here are the permissions given on the machine:

```
drwxrwxrwx   4 root     root         512 May 16 09:32 STC_10
drwxrw-rw-   4 root     root         512 May  5 11:22 STC_11
```

Now here is the Problem:

```
cd STC_11
-bash: cd: STC_11: Permission denied
```

But this one works:

```
-bash-4.0$ cd STC_10
-bash-4.0$ ls
Codemgr_wsdata  src
```

Why do we need execution permission to do a reach that directory `STC_11`? Wont read-write permissions suffice?

An `ls` command on `STC_11` would work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the following demonstration, I created a few directories:

```
$ mkdir read_only
$ mkdir exec_only
$ mkdir r_e
$ touch read_only/cant_open
$ echo foo > read_only/cant_open 
$ echo bar > exec_only/cant_find
$ echo baz > r_e/normal
$ chmod 400 read_only/
$ chmod 100 exec_only/
$ chmod 500 r_e/
```

Read permissions are sufficient to *list the contents of the directory*: `ls(1)` can't find *details* about the file, but it can tell you the name of the file.

```
$ ls read_only/
ls: cannot access read_only/cant_open: Permission denied
cant_open
```

But read-only access doesn't let you *traverse* the directory:

```
$ cat read_only/cant_open 
cat: read_only/cant_open: Permission denied
```

Execute permissions are sufficient to *traverse the directory* (including `cd`), but you can't list the contents:

```
$ ls exec_only/
ls: cannot open directory exec_only/: Permission denied
```

Even though you can't get a listing of files in the directory, you can still traverse the directory:

```
$ cat exec_only/cant_find
bar
```

Both read and execute permissions work as you expect:

```
$ ls r_e
normal
$ cat r_e/normal 
baz
```

While it is initially confusing to have permission to list the files in a directory but not be able to *do* anything with them, and it is also confusing to have permission to *do* things with files but not be able to list them, it is part of Unix's tradition of simple mechanisms being used for clever things: these two elements alone make it easy to implement [Capability-based security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security). If I were to place a few thousand files in the directory, but only wanted *some* people to read files meant for them, I could easily pick unguessable filenames, and give out the filenames when people give me money to read the files. :)

Or, maybe you have a dozen clients, and you want them all to have access to a directory of files meant for them. If you place all the client information into a single directory with only execute access, they could never determine your other clients, unless they already *know* that the other person is a client.

Answer (score 3):

By definition 'x' permission for directories has a special meaning--it means you have permission to 'cd' into it.

Comment: @Karmakaze: to list the contents of a directory .. we need to spill out its inode structure ....can't that be achieved via a r permission itself? I am just curious about the file system design.

Answer (score 1):

The `x` permission doesn't just mean "Execute".  It depends on where it's applied.  On a file it gives permission to execute the file.  On a directory it gives permission to change to the directory.  I don't think it has much to do with the structure of the filesystem.